# Nivo Circle Packing, circles are moving/reordered on any action on page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nivo-react

I'm using React Nivo CirclePacking to represent data hierarchy & the relation between the hierarchy levels an example of levels can be: Year(depth 0) > Province(depth 1) > Citie(depth 2), the chart is rendering fine & working but when the user click almost any where on the page the chart bubbles are rearranged.

[Here's a clip that shows the unwanted behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Atm2Z.gif)

I don't want this rearrangement to be triggered each time I click somewhere (in/out the chart), to make the issue more clear if I where to remove "year" from the hierarchy levels (e.g hierarchy: Province(depth0) > cities(deoth1); the bug goes away. so when I click on the same places the circles are not rearranged.

Here's the object Nivo Chart reads from, if hierarchy was (Year(depth 0) > Province(depth 1) > Citie(depth 2)):

```
{
"id": "DATA0",
"source": "DATA",
"objId": "DATA0",
"children": [
    {
        "id": "AY2122",
        "source": "ACADEMIC_YEAR",
        "objId": "AY2122",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "AY2122-PROVINCE1",
                "source": "PROVINCE",
                "objId": "PROVINCE1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "AY2122-PROVINCE1-CITY34",
                        "source": "CITY",
                        "objId": "CITY34",
                        "buildings": [],
                        "nodeSize": 10
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "AY2122-PROVINCE1-CITY35",
                        "source": "CITY",
                        "objId": "CITY35",
                        "buildings": [
                            {
                                "source": "BUILDING",
                                "objId": "19"
                            },
                            {
                                "source": "BUILDING",
                                "objId": "48"
                            }
                        ],
                        "nodeSize": 30
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "AY2122-PROVINCE2",
                "source": "PROVINCE",
                "objId": "PROVINCE2",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "AY2122-PROVINCE2-CITY4",
                        "source": "CITY",
                        "objId": "CITY4",
                        "buildings": [],
                        "nodeSize": 10
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "AY2122-PROVINCE2-CITY18",
                        "source": "CITY",
                        "objId": "CITY18",
                        "buildings": [
                            {
                                "source": "BUILDING",
                                "objId": "8"
                            }
                        ],
                        "nodeSize": 20
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "AY2122-PROVINCE3",
                "source": "PROVINCE",
                "objId": "PROVINCE3",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "AY2122-PROVINCE3-CITY33",
                        "source": "CITY",
                        "objId": "CITY33",
                        "buildings": [
                            {
                                "source": "BUILDING",
                                "objId": "77"
                            },
                            {
                                "source": "BUILDING",
                                "objId": "108"
                            },
                            {
                                "source": "BUILDING",
                                "objId": "189"
                            }
                        ],
                        "nodeSize": 40
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "AY2223",
        "source": "ACADEMIC_YEAR",
        "objId": "AY2223",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "AY2223-PROVINCE1",
                "source": "PROVINCE",
                "objId": "PROVINCE1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "AY2223-PROVINCE1-CITY29",
                        "source": "CITY",
                        "objId": "CITY29",
                        "buildings": [
                            {
                                "source": "BUILDING",
                                "objId": "29"
                            },
                            {
                                "source": "BUILDING",
                                "objId": "46"
                            }
                        ],
                        "nodeSize": 30
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "AY2223-PROVINCE1-CITY34",
                        "source": "CITY",
                        "objId": "CITY34",
                        "buildings": [],
                        "nodeSize": 10
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "AY2223-PROVINCE2",
                "source": "PROVINCE",
                "objId": "PROVINCE2",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "AY2223-PROVINCE2-CITY4",
                        "source": "CITY",
                        "objId": "CITY4",
                        "buildings": [],
                        "nodeSize": 10
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "AY2223-PROVINCE2-CITY20",
                        "source": "CITY",
                        "objId": "CITY20",
                        "buildings": [
                            {
                                "source": "BUILDING",
                                "objId": "198"
                            }
                        ],
                        "nodeSize": 20
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "AY2223-PROVINCE3",
                "source": "PROVINCE",
                "objId": "PROVINCE3",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "AY2223-PROVINCE3-CITY33",
                        "source": "CITY",
                        "objId": "CITY33",
                        "buildings": [
                            {
                                "source": "BUILDING",
                                "objId": "77"
                            },
                            {
                                "source": "BUILDING",
                                "objId": "108"
                            }
                        ],
                        "nodeSize": 30
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

And here is the Nivo circlePacking component:

```
const BubbleChart =(props)=>{

    const clickTimer = useRef();

    const [nivoObject, setNivoObject] = useState({});
    const [bigData, setBigData] = useState({});
    const [hierarchyCopy, setHierarchyCopy] = useState();
    const [selectedSchoolId, setSelectedSchooId] = useState();

    const [zoomedNode, setZoomedNode] = useState();
    const [nodeZero, setNodeZero] = useState();
    const [selectedNode, setSelectedNode] = useState();
    const [selectedNodeArPath, setSelectedNodeArPath] = useState();

    const [finalDepth, setFinalDepth] = useState(2);
   

return (
  <ResponsiveCirclePacking

                            data={nivoObject}
                            id="id"
                            value="nodeSize"
                            margin={{ top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20 }}
                            padding={13}

                            zoomedId={zoomedNode?.id}
                            onClick={(node, event) => {

                                setSelectedNode(node);
                                clearTimeout(clickTimer.current);

                                if (event.detail === 1) {
                                    // On single click

                                    clickTimer.current = setTimeout(() => {
                                        setZoomedNode(zoomedNode?.id === node.id ? null : node);
                                    }, 300);
                                }
                            }}

                            enableLabels={true}
                            label={(dat) => true && `${bigData[dat.data.source][dat.data.objId]["title"]}`}
                            labelComponent={(labelProps) => {
                                return (
                                    <HighChartCustomeLabel
                                        {...labelProps}
                                        zoomedNode={zoomedNode}
                                        submitHandler={nodeClickHandler}
                                        finalDepth={finalDepth}
                                    />
                                );
                            }}
                            labelsFilter={(label) => {

                                if (label.node.depth === 0 && !zoomedNode) {
                                    setNodeZero(label.node);
                                    setZoomedNode(label.node);
                                }

                                if (zoomedNode?.depth === finalDepth) {
                                    return (label.node.depth === zoomedNode?.depth);
                                } else {
                                    return (label.node.depth === zoomedNode?.depth + 1);
                                }
                            }}
                            labelsSkipRadius={10}
                            labelTextColor={"#fff"}

                            tooltip={CustomTooltip}

                            borderWidth={0}
                            colorBy="depth"
                            colors={["#4880FF33", "#00A353cc", "#52477199", "#493F6499"]}
                            motionConfig="slow"
                        />
 );
};
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think we need more than just the data object to help you

Comment: I added the Nivo component code.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the Nivo component  is having trouble sorting the circles on the screen while rendering, that is because there's a lot of circles with the same size, and so on any chance of re-rendering the chart is trying to sort the circles again.

To over come this I add [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) to every circle size ("nodeSize" in my example), this reduced the percentage of similarity between the circles sizes, & I removed those fractions when I wanted the real value back.

This maybe not the best way to do it, but the issue was gone thank God.